# give public access to s3 bucket rather than serving static website for aws serverless application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-serverless

i am new to aws serverless, and trying to host django app in aws serverless.

now aws serverless uses s3 bucket for static website hosting which cost around $0.50 (I am in free tier).

my question is instead of hosting static website can i not give public access to s3 bucket? as it would save me money. is it possible to use public bucket for aws serverless?

Comment: An example of something similar: https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/serve-a-django-app-from-an-aws-lambda-function/

Comment: You will need to clarify what you are asking.  The static website hosting feature of S3 does not have any additonal charges, when compared to the cost of simply making the bucket public without the static website hosting feature active.

Comment: Static website hosting on s3 bucket is $0.50, I simply want to make bucket public and use it for serverless django.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hosting static content on S3 is the most cost cost effective way to serve content.  I would suggest to keep your bucket private and enable cloudfront as distribution (CDN) point in front of S3.  That allows to keep a cache at the edge, close to your customers and to slightly lower the outgoing bandwidth costs (Cloudfront outgoing bandwidth costs is lower than S3 : in the US $0.085/Gb vs $0.090/GB)

This article will give you detailed instructions how to do so https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/

I explained the high level steps on my blog too : https://www.stormacq.com/2018/10/17/migrated-to-serverless.html

Comment: This is okay, but can I give public access to bucket and use it for django serverless?

Comment: I don’t know Django Serverless. If it is producing a bunch of static content (html, css, images and JS), yes it can be hosted on a public S3 bucket. Cloudfront is optional but recommended as it improves customer experience and lower your costs. It also allows to keep your S3 bucket private.